# Module needs to be created twice in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If the app.userModule.services module is created first (index.js) and then is instanced to create the factory (UserService.js), why do I get the following error?

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $resourceProvider
>   <- $resource <- **UserService**

Only if I create the module in UserService (**added [ 'ngResource' ]**) the application works right.

```
angular.module('guotay.userModule.services', [ 'ngResource' ]).factory(...
```

**The question**: Why the content of user/services/index.js is ignored??

The project structure and some parts of the code:

[image: Structure]

index.html:

```
<script src="app/app.js"></script>
<script src="app/components/user/index.js"></script>
<script src="app/components/user/controllers/index.js"></script>
<script src="app/components/user/controllers/LoginCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="app/components/user/services/index.js"></script>
<script src="app/components/user/services/UserService.js"></script>
```

And the same with other modules

user/index.js

```
angular.module('app.userModule', [ 'app.userModule.controllers',
            'app.userModule.services' ]).config(function config($routeProvider) {...});
```

user/services/index.js

```
angular.module('app.userModule.services', []);
```

user/services/UserService.js

```
var serviceId = 'UserService';

angular.module('app.userModule.services').factory(serviceId, [ '$resource',
        serviceFunc ]);

function serviceFunc($resource) {...}
```

app.js

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ngCookies', 'app.userModule', 'app.newsEntryModule'])
    .config(...)
    .run(function($rootScope, $location, $cookieStore, UserService) {
           UserService.get(function(user) {
                $rootScope.user = user;
                $location.path(originalPath);
            });});
```

I have other services with the same implementation, and they work right with the creation of the module in the index.js, but they not appear in app.js.

Comment: Why aren't you listing `ngResource` as a dependency in user/services/index.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `angular.module('someName', ['list', 'of', 'dependencies']);`
is the way you *define* a module and `angular.module('someName')` is the way you obtain an instance (retrieve) of an already defined module.

If you define the same module twice the second definition will *overwrite* the first one - you will loose everything you defined in the first one.

[It's all in the docs.](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#creation-versus-retrieval)

Update: 
The browser first loads `app.js` and only after it loads `app/components/user/services/index.js`
So any code in `app.js` depending on stuff from `index.js` will break.

This is the reason you cannot reference `UserService` in `app.js`. It's not yet declared.

Comment: I know that, I defined first in user/services/index.js and I try to obtain the instance in user/services/UserService.js but without success. That is why I have to defined twice, because the first definition in index.js it does not work, it is always ignored the index.js (it is explained in the first lines of my post)

Comment: But why are you trying to inject `UserService` in app.js when `module('app')` does not list `'app.userModule.services'` as a dependency? And even if you did how is `app.js` supposed to reference it when you are loading `'app/components/user/services/UserService.js'` later?

Comment: app.js lists app.userModule, app.userModule lists app.userModule.services and there is the functionality. In the index.html first are the index.js with the definitions and then the use of the instances that are previously defined in these indexes. I follow this structure and it works well in the application except in this case. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: But if the browser first loads `app.js` and only after it loads `app/components/user/services/index.js` how can you expect to reference `UserService` in `app.js` when it's not yet _declared_?

Comment: Ok, I understand it! I think that this explanation is what I am looking for. If you would change your first answer with this, I would set it as valid answer. Thank you Sergiu!